# Issue mounting a network drive using fstab

Tags: ubuntu, cifs, shared-folders

I'm having a bit of a mare at the moment:

I recently rebooted my host server, any my Ubuntu server 20.04 server was unable to mount a network drive again. I had a small issue where the `systemd-resolved` service wasn't running properly, but I was able to get that sorted.

But it still doesn't want to mount the network drive.

The mount point definitely exists

```
ldadmin@LD-DOCKER01:~$ ls /mnt/
plex_data  plex_media  vuetorrent
```

Here's my fstab file

```
ldadmin@LD-DOCKER01:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
//10.11.10.10/media /mnt/plex_data cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/ldadmin/SMBCreds/Media,iocharset=utf8 0 0
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-dKtbpdhrXBO21N1jbjxfSX0xwSKAPf3uvec11xtX4odywT1Q47kYZmxyvw0eQ7ap / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5dbadd90-cf4b-4cec-8b4b-ac149a5cd306 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1400-9711 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
#//192.168.1.100/vuetorrent mnt/vuetorrent cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/ldadmin/SMBCreds/.Media,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Trying to re-map the network drive

```
ldadmin@LD-DOCKER01:~$ sudo mount -a
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Permissions on the local mount point

```
ldadmin@LD-DOCKER01:~$ ls -l /mnt/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 12 17:28 plex_data
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1 19:32 plex_media
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1 20:11 vuetorrent
```

I'm not terribly well versed in Linux, so I'm not sure where I should be looking to get some more specifics.

So far I've tried manually mounting the network drive with

```
ldadmin@LD-DOCKER01:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=*USERNAME*,password=*PASSWORD* //10.11.10.10/media /mnt/plex_data//10.11.10.10/media /mnt/plex_data
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

I've also removed and recreated the mount point, reinstalled cifs-utils, tried mounting to another folder in /mnt/

I am able to ping the server where the network share is located as well.

Verified that I can access/mount that share from a different windows machine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have tried the `mount` command with only `/mnt/plex_data` instead of with two mounpoints? Add `-vvv` to the `mount` command and add the output to the question.

Comment: What does syslog (journal) say? ("Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)")

Answer (score 0):

Update.

I checked again this morning, and the drive was mounted as expected. Not sure what was going on there, but all seems to be good now.

Comment: This kind of question and answer is completely useless for anybody. If you don't know what the problem was, or what fixed it, consider deleting the question!